# Custom web component using Svelte (a "tabs" component)

Tags: svelte

I am developing a custom reusable web component using Svelte (a "tabs" component), I would like to know is my code is idiomatic Svelte and also any suggestion for improvement is welcome.

### Illustration:

[image]

I believe that component can be useful. It can be used as a menu widget which is very easy to use or as a pseudo routing mechanism in a web app, for instance, so I wanted to share it, but before I do so I would like to gather some suggestions for improvements.

### Here is how the component is used:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Tabs  from "./Tabs.svelte"

    let menu = [
        { label: "Choice 1", content: "One" },
        { label: "Choice 2", content: "Two" },
        { label: "Choice 3", content: "Three" },
    ];
</script>

<main>
    <Tabs {menu}/>
</main>
```

and here is how I coded said component:

I'm not sure the use of `getElementsByClassName` is considered idiomatic Svelte

### Question:

Is it possible to modify the code so as not to use `getElementsByClassName`  ?

### Code for the component:

```
<script lang="ts">


  // Prop :
  export let menu;

  let items = Array<string>();
  let visibles = Array<string>();
  let actives = Array<string>();
  let display = Array<string>();
  let index = new Int32Array(menu.length);

  for (let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
    items.push(`b${i}`);
    visibles.push("hidden");
    actives.push("btn");
    display.push("none");
    index[i] = i;
  }
  visibles[0] = "visible";
  actives[0] = "btn_active";
  display[0] = "block";

  function handleClick(e) {
    console.log({ name: e.target.name });
    console.log({ name: e.target });

    let index = items.indexOf(e.target.name);
    console.log({ index: index });

    // Blocks (content)
    for (let item in items) {
      if (Number(item) === index) {
        visibles[Number(item)] = "visible";
        display[Number(item)] = "block";
      } else {
        visibles[Number(item)] = "hidden";
        display[Number(item)] = "none";
      }
    }

    // Buttons (header)
    for (let b of document.getElementsByClassName("btn_active")) {
      b.className = "btn";
    }
    e.target.className = "btn_active";
  }
</script>

<main>
  <!-- Tabs nav bar -->
  <div>
    <nav>
      {#each index as i}
        <button class={actives[i]} on:click={handleClick} name={items[i]}>
          {menu[i].label}
        </button>
      {/each}
    </nav>
  </div>

  <!-- Items in tabs -->
  <div>
    {#each index as i}
      <div style="visibility:{visibles[i]};display:{display[i]};">
        <div><h1>{menu[i].content}</h1></div>
      </div>
    {/each}
  </div>
</main>
```